# createAddOwnerTx executes a blank transaction

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm trying to add a new owner to my Safe Account through the API.
These are the steps I'm doing:

**1. Create the adapter**

```
    export async function createAdapter(
      adminMnemonic: any,
      providerURL: any,
      adminAddress: string | undefined
    ) {
      const provider = new HDWalletProvider(adminMnemonic, providerURL);
      const web3Instance = new Web3(provider as any);
    
      const ethAdapter = new Web3Adapter({
        web3: web3Instance as any,
        signerAddress: adminAddress,
      });
    
      return ethAdapter;
    }
```

**2. Connect to the safe wallet**

```
export async function safeWalletConnection(
  ethAdapter: any,
  userSafeAddress: any
) {
  const safeSdk = await Safe.create({
    ethAdapter,
    safeAddress: userSafeAddress,
  });

  return safeSdk;
}
```

After executing these two functions, I can check the connection is working because I print some messages with wallet information:

```
  const address = await safeSDK.getAddress();
  const owners = await safeSDK.getOwners();
  const threshold = await safeSDK.getThreshold();
  console.log(
    "address: ",
    address,
    " owners: ",
    owners,
    " threshold: ",
    threshold
  );
```

And this log returns:

> address:  0x6B5c63b767b4C70C6371a42B5B854209e361D0C7  owners:  [ '0x7Fa68d2da385b9Eaf9009D5E9E7fbf92B79778bd' ]  threshold:  1

The problem comes when I execute the createAddOwnerTx function:

```
    const tx = await safeSDK.createAddOwnerTx({
      ownerAddress: externalWallet?.wallet_account || "",
    });

    const txResponse = await safeSDK.executeTransaction(tx);
    await txResponse.transactionResponse?.wait();
```

This is the txResponse I'm getting back:

> {
> hash: '0xfb1aa8862096bce8e90707d16936398758d72fd65330f5965e5887e731de715b',
> promiEvent: Web3PromiEvent {
> _emitter: EventEmitter {
> _events: [Object: null prototype],
> _eventsCount: 1,
> _maxListeners: undefined,
> [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
> },
> _promise: Promise {  },
> [Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)]: 'Promise'
> },
> options: { from: '0x7Fa68d2da385b9Eaf9009D5E9E7fbf92B79778bd', gas: '100466' }
> }

If you check the tx hash on Goerli, you will se the tx is not adding a new owner to my account:

[image: This is the unique event the tx emits]

I don't know what is happening.

Comment: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xfb1aa8862096bce8e90707d16936398758d72fd65330f5965e5887e731de715b the transaction doesn't contain any call data

Comment: Hi @mikheevm, that is the problem. The tx is doing nothing when it supposedly should add an owner to my safe account. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the ownerAddress you're passing is defined?

Comment: Yes, it is. I can print it and I get the expected result.

Comment: In this case, please create an issue in the repo, since it's related to the problem in the package and is not a general development question.